# Call to the 'userConnect()' method skips

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm posting this question because I'm clueless of what went wrong.
I recently coded a Client-Server Interactive File Sharing Application using select() API as part of my Homework. 
It works perfectly on my laptop. But I was told to get it running on university servers, because that is where my project will be tested. I made sure my application is working and submitted the project.

When my app start's off it calls 'getMYIPAddress()' method to fetch host's local IP address which I later used it for flagging self connections. Now problem is, If I remove the 'cout << ' in this method, It skips 'userConnect()' routine.

```
void getMyIPAddress (char* command, char* port) {
    struct hostent *he;
    struct in_addr ipv4addr;
    char dnsIP[] = "8.8.8.8";                                   // Google DNS IP
    char dnsPort[] = "53" ;                                     // Google DNS TCP Port
    // Converting IP to struct in_addr type     
    inet_pton(AF_INET, dnsIP, &ipv4addr);
    // getting host details from IP address
    he = gethostbyaddr(&ipv4addr, sizeof ipv4addr, AF_INET);
    cout << "BAZINGA!" << endl;
    // Connecting to google DNS to get IP address of this process
    userConnect (he->h_name, dnsPort, port, command);
}
```

I did remove this unnecessary 'cout' before submitting. Now It doesn't enter userConnect() which connects to google DNS and retreives IP address. If I keep it, it works fine.

I didn't post this question to waste your valuable time. If you can comprehend what possibly could cause this, you'll ease up my frustration.

EDIT::@Tanmay's Answer:
"I moved the cout<< into the userConnect() routine before it connects. It didn't work."
"There is no bug in 'userConnect()' it just works as it should when it is called."

EDIT: I realized where it went wrong. Please see the follow up post.

[Variable is being changed for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214272/variable-is-being-changed-for-some-reason)

Thanks,sarath.

Comment: How can you tell it doesn't enter userConnect()?  Is it because you put a debug print inside userConnect() and you don't see that debug print being printed?  (If so, some possible reasons why:  You aren't flushing cout; or execution is blocking before it gets to the print statement; or the print statement is in a conditional path that wasn't taken; or there is more than one definition of userConnect (e.g. due to argument overloading) and the one that is being called isn't the one you put the debug print in; or (conceivably) someone is playing games with #define)

Comment: Jeremy, I apologize to let this question open. I could not close it from my mobile. Anyhow I edited my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility of a bug in either `gethostbyaddr` or `userConnect` that is being resolved due to cout. Most probably due to flushing the output buffer.

Please try replacing it with some other code and share the results of your experiment if you can.

Good luck.

Comment: 'gethostbyaddr' is method in sys/socket.h!It cannot possibly be buggy! Also userConnect is not being called at all. Please see my edit.