# Variable is being changed for some reason

Tags: c++, sockets

This post is follow up to
[Call to the 'userConnect()' method skips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213452/call-to-the-userconnect-method-skips)

Correction to my last post, It is actually entering userConnect() method but some how SETUP_ERROR flag is being changed. As you can see in my userConnect() the places I changed SETUP_ERROR, I clearly printed what the error could be.

Now with the 'cout <<' in 'getMyIPAddress()' method, the SETUP_ERROR is 0 and enters into IF loop in userConnect() and works perfect. When I remove it, Somehow SETUP_ERROR is being changed to 1 and printing "SETUP_ERROR".

Cannot figure out why SETUP_ERROR being changed to 1, I know 'cout' has nothing to do with this but what could it be. Beats me.

getMyIPAdress():

```
void getMyIPAddress (char* command, char* port) {
    struct hostent *he;
    struct in_addr ipv4addr;
    char dnsIP[] = "8.8.8.8";                                   // Google DNS IP
    char dnsPort[] = "53" ;                                     // Google DNS TCP Port
    // Converting IP to struct in_addr type     
    inet_pton(AF_INET, dnsIP, &ipv4addr);
    // getting host details from IP address
    he = gethostbyaddr(&ipv4addr, sizeof ipv4addr, AF_INET);
    cout << "bazinga!" << endl;
    // Connecting to google DNS to get IP address of this process
    userConnect (he->h_name, dnsPort, port, command);
}
```

userConnect():

```
void userConnect ( char* sIP, char* sPort, string my_port, char* command )
{
    int numbytes;
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    char rbuf[MAXDATASIZE];
    int rv;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    struct addrinfo *servinfo,*p,hints;
    int sockfd;
    int SETUP_ERROR;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    // Getting address related information 
    // flagging invalid ip addresses 
    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(sIP, sPort, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        cout << "getaddrinfo: " << endl << gai_strerror(rv) << endl;
        cout << " Invalid IP Address! " << endl;
        SETUP_ERROR = 1;
    }else
    {
        int count;
        for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
            if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
                perror("client: socket");
                continue;
            }

            if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
                close(sockfd);
                perror("client: connect");
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }
        // flagging invalid port numbers
        if (p == NULL) {
            cout << stderr << "client: failed to connect" << endl;
            cout  << "Invalid Port Number! " << endl;
            SETUP_ERROR = 1;
        }
    }
    if (SETUP_ERROR != 1) {

        inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr), s, sizeof s);       // gettin printable ip
        freeaddrinfo(servinfo);                                                                 // don't need anymore
        int len;
        // Functionalities based on input commands
        if (strcmp(command,"REGISTER")==0) {
            // client adding server as default first connection
            conn_head = insert(conn_head , server_IP, sPort, sockfd-OFFSET );
            servfd = sockfd;
            len = my_port.length();
            // sending client's listening port number to server 
            if (send (sockfd, &len, sizeof( len ), 0) == -1)
                perror("send packet length");
            if (send(sockfd, my_port.c_str(), len, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            // adding socket fd to master list 
            addFdToMaster(sockfd);
        }else if(strcmp(command, "MYIP")==0) {
            /* Next 10 line code snippet is taken from a blog online! Cant find it anymore to post reference ! :) */
            //get local socket info::
            struct sockaddr_in local_addr;
                socklen_t addr_len = sizeof(local_addr);
            if (getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&local_addr, &addr_len) < 0) {
                perror("getsockname");
            }
            /* get peer ip addr */
            char my_ip[INET_ADDRSTRLEN];
            if (inet_ntop(local_addr.sin_family, &(local_addr.sin_addr), myip, sizeof(myip)) == NULL) {
                perror("inet_ntop");
            }
            else
                cout << "HOST IP Address:: " << myip << endl;
        }
    }else
        cout << "SETUP_ERROR" << endl;
}
```

Comment: The `my_port` parameter to `userConnect()` is a `string`, but you're passing in a `char*`. That can't be right.

Comment: @user1118321 - `std::string` has an implicit conversion from `char *` so this isn't a problem.

Comment: @^^^ : As I said, The code works perfectly fine. SOCKET_ERROR variable get's changed.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  If it's Visual Studio, then all you need to do is set a data breakpoint on SETUP_ERROR (give the address of the variable), run the program at "full speed" and when it changes for any reason, the debugger will pop up and pause the program.  I'm sure gdb has something like this also (if you're using gcc).

Comment: @Paul: I'm using gcc, I'll check if gdb has this.

Comment: I've hardly used gdb, but it would be unfortunate if gdb didn't have this capability.

Comment: Me too. I'm currently running in university server, It only has gcc!

Comment: @MattMcNabb Oh right. Duh. I was thinking the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialize  `SETUP_ERROR`, nor set it to `0`.  The test `if (SETUP_ERROR != 1)` is testing an uninitialized variable, in the cases where you seem to be expecting it to be `0`.

To explain what you're seeing, your compiler is placing `SETUP_ERROR` on the stack, and since there's no initialization, it is just assuming a value from whatever bytes are in the memory location that the stack grows into. These could be affected by what you were doing in the other function.

Comment: It defaults to zero. Thanks though.

Comment: `int` variables do not default to anything in C++.

Comment: Well, Thanks for pointing out. But my compiler does take it as zero. I'll make it a point though.

Comment: Code works fine with that cout << "bazzinga" line.! How about that? :)

Comment: Change to `int SETUP_ERROR = 0;` and remove the bazinga, see if it works.

Comment: Boom! It does. Yeah. But what on earth bazinga did?

Comment: I explained in my answer..:) local variables for functions are typically allocated on a stack structure, so when you call `cout`, the `cout` itself uses up some stack temporarily. After it returns and the stack pops back to where it was, those bytes don't actually change. Then when `userConnect` grabs some stack for its local variables, it gets the chunk that `cout` previously used, and any variables you don't actually initialize just end up with whatever contents correspond to their location.

Comment: In the rest of my code I didn't initialize int varibles to 0. It worked fine.

Comment: When you say whatever value, SETUP_ERROR gets exactly 1 without cout. Interesting. Thanks

Comment: It was just chance that your other local variables happened to get sections of stack that were already 0. It's certainly not something you should rely on, as this case shows.

Comment: Yeah. Lesson learnt. I'm gonna loose many points for this hw. who cares. Its been fun.